# Trying to get channelId from message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get the `channelId` from `message` but this line of my code

```js
if (msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelid) === suggestionsChannelId && !author.bot)
```

is throwing this error:

> ReferenceError: channelid is not defined

My code looks like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js") 

const { suggestionsChannelId, suggestionsWebhookUrl } = require(__dirname + "/../config/servers/818776716218335262.json")

const webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient(suggestionsWebhookUrl);

module.exports = {
    name: "message",

    run(msg) {
        const { author } = msg

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(msg)

        if (msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId) === suggestionsChannelId && !author.bot) {
            webhookClient.send({
                username: author.username,
                avatarURL: author.displayAvatarURL(),
                embeds: [embed],
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is correct. You haven't defined the variable `channelId` before you attempt to use it. (Hint: you probably want to get the channel ID from something)

Comment: i not defined it cause i want to get the channelid from this message so how i can get it? @tehhowch

Comment: `msg.channel.id` will return the ID of the channel in which the message was sent in.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you are **never defining** the `variable channelid`. You can get the `channel ID` from your `message` like this:

```js
const channelId = msg.channel.id
```

Now you're able to get the actual `GuildChannel`:

```js
const channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
```